# How do you know which interface a broadcast message came from?

Tags: python, c, sockets, network-programming, udp

I have a rather odd situation where I will have multiple interfaces connected to the same network. When I receive a broadcast or multicast message, I would like to know what interface it came from. It there a way to do that in C or ideally Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious one would be to bind several sockets, each to *one interface only* - do not listen to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Antti, thanks for that suggestion. How do you bind to a specific interface and still receive broadcast messages?

Comment: @dlsm You *will* receive broadcast messages on any socket. You need to enumerate all the interfaces that you want to listen to and bind to them. This is platform-dependent I believe.